# How can I set the format of labels?

Tags: c#, graph, axis-labels, teechart

So, I am trying to plot the graph and I have 3 fastlines in the Tchart, It seems like the graph are correct but there is something I need to set with labels of axes, What I get is this,
[my graph with x labels as 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ]
http://s8.postimage.org/t7tappekl/image.png

[I want something like this]

http://s7.postimage.org/amltkb917/untitled.png
and what I want to get is something like this ,  the actual  x labels as these . X labels are seconds.
I have already tried setting the valueformat for series and chart lablels. It did not work,

How should I do this? and also I am trying to zoom and scroll up the y axes to set the focus like the image 2. the y graph always starts from 0 , but initially is there any way to set the focus on starting point i.e.81

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set desired increment for the bottom axis labels using the so called Increment property, for example:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = 0.1;
```

For changing axes range you can use SetMinMax or Minimum and Maximum properties:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Left.SetMinMax(50, 100);
```

or

```
  tChart1.Axes.Left.AutomaticMinimum = false;
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum = 50;
  tChart1.Axes.Left.AutomaticMaximum = false;
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Maximum = 100;
```

Finally, you can change the chart view perspective changing some of the following properties:

```
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = true;
  tChart1.Aspect.Orthogonal = false;
  tChart1.Aspect.Chart3DPercent = 50;
  tChart1.Aspect.Elevation = 0;
  tChart1.Aspect.Rotation = 345;
  tChart1.Aspect.Perspective = 50;
```

BTW, you'll find more information about axis settings in tutorial 4. Tutorials can be found a TeeChart's program group.

Comment: Thank you so much. and one more question, is there any equivalent of chart.canvas property in C# , the closest I could guess was graphics3d. but it is not working , I really appreciate the help.

Comment: and the x labels are for some reason shown as integer , it should be the float and should show like 0.75,0.4 , but it shows 0 ,0 . I tried to set the labels.valueformat property, but it didnot do the trick

Comment: @saumilpatel yes, you should use tChart1.Graphics3d. You may need to call tChart1.Draw() after though. Alternatively you can use "g" argument in the AfterDraw event. If this doesn't help please let us know what you are trying to do exactly. That's probably food for a new question ;-). Regarding X labels, you can force them like this:       tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.ValueFormat = "0.0"; but it may be they don't fit in the chart. Try resizing the chart to see if it's a space issue.